# Proving $\frac12(u-v)^2\left[\log(1-\frac{2uv}{u^2+v^2})\right]^2+\frac12(u+v)^2\left[\log(1+\frac{2uv}{u^2+v^2})\right]^2\leq4v^2$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the following log inequality:

$$\frac{1}{2}(u-v)^2 \left[\log\left(1-\frac{2uv}{u^2+v^2}\right)\right]^2+\frac{1}{2}(u+v)^2 \left[\log\left(1+\frac{2uv}{u^2+v^2}\right)\right]^2\leq 4v^2$$
Here $u,v$ are variables.

Things I have tried:

1. Considering $\log (1+x)\leq x$ for $x>0$. This does not work for $x<0$ though.
2. Jensen's inequality.

EDIT: On dividing throughout by $u^2$, we can re-write this as

$$\frac{1}{2}(s-1)^2 \left(\log(1-\frac{2s}{1+s^2})\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}(s+1)^2 \left(\log(1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2})\right)^2\leq 4s^2$$

How would one start with an inequality like this?

Comment: As a hint, the left-hand side depends on $u$ but the right-hand side does not. A useful step in this situation is maximising the LHS over $u$ and thus reducing it to an expression in $v$ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that, for all $s\in \mathbb{R}$ with $s\ne \pm 1$,
$$\frac{1}{2}(s-1)^2 \ln^2\left(1-\frac{2s}{1+s^2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}(s+1)^2 \ln^2(1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2})\le 4s^2. \tag{1}$$

It suffices to prove that, for all $s\in \mathbb{R}$ with $s \ne \pm 1$,
$$\frac{1}{2}(s+1)^2 \ln^2\left(1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2}\right)\le 2s^2. \tag{2}$$
(*Note*: If (2) is true, letting $s \to -s$, we have $\frac{1}{2}(s - 1)^2 \ln^2\left(1 - \frac{2s}{1+s^2}\right)\le 2s^2$ which, together with (2), yields (1).)

- If $s \ge 0$ with $s \ne 1$, it suffices to prove that
  $$(1 + s) \ln\left(1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2}\right)\le 2s$$
  or
  $$\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{2s}{1 + s}\right) \ge 1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2}$$
  or (using $\mathrm{e}^x \ge 1 + x + \frac12x^2$ for all $x \ge 0$)
  $$1 + \frac{2s}{1 + s} + \frac12\left(\frac{2s}{1 + s}\right)^2
  \ge 1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2}$$
  or
  $$\frac{4s^4}{(1 + s)^2(1 + s^2)}\ge 0$$
  which is true.

$\phantom{2}$

- If $- 1 < s < 0$, it suffices to prove that
  $$-(1 + s) \ln\left(1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2}\right)\le -2s$$
  or
  $$1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2} \ge \frac{1}{\mathrm{exp}(\frac{-2s}{1+s})}. \tag{3}$$
  Using $\mathrm{e}^x \ge 1 + x + \frac12 x^2$ for all $x \ge 0$, we have
  $$\frac{1}{\mathrm{exp}(\frac{-2s}{1+s})}
  \le \frac{1}{1 + \frac{-2s}{1+s} + \frac12(\frac{-2s}{1+s})^2}
  = 1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2}.$$
  Thus, (3) is true.

$\phantom{2}$

- If $s < -1$, it suffices to prove that
  $$(1 + s) \ln\left(1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2}\right)\le -2s$$
  or
  $$1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2}\ge \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}(\frac{2s}{1 + s})}$$
  or (using $\mathrm{e}^x \ge 1 + x + \frac12 x^2$ for all $x \ge 0$)
  $$1+\frac{2s}{1+s^2} \ge \frac{1}{1 + \frac{2s}{1 + s} + \frac12(\frac{2s}{1 + s})^2}$$
  or
  $$\frac{4s(1 + s)^3}{(1+s^2)(5s^2 + 4s + 1)}\ge 0$$
  which is true.

We are done.

Comment: Can you explain how proving $(2)$ is sufficient to prove $(1)$?

Comment: @ShubhavJain If (2) is true, letting $s \to -s$, we have $\frac{1}{2}(s-1)^2 \ln^2\left(1-\frac{2s}{1+s^2}\right)\le 2s^2$, then adding (2) and this, we get (1).

Comment: Brilliant! Simple, but it just didn't click.

Comment: @RiverLi- I was asking about this proof as a part of a research paper that I will be publishing in the near future. Would you like to be acknowledged for it? If you would, I can contact you in the near future from my professional email ID with details.

Comment: @matilda Thanks. No need for that. It is not a difficult problem. Feel free to use this proof.